# What all fetch modes are there for PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I am just getting started using PDO.

I am wondering if there is a list of all the available FETCH_* modes and what each does?

I found this page of the manuals that covers [`setFetchMode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) which even has this line in it:

> The fetch mode must be one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants.

But I see nothing that lists what all is available?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php will tell you all he constants, including the fetch mode constants. You can also find more details in the `PDOStatement::fetch` documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php